# Reloading a div with ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, struts2-jquery

I am following this tutorial on struts2-jquery plugin [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/jquery-plugin-easy-ajax-and-widget-integration.html)

But the ajax call seems to be not working, when I click the link nothing happens. Here is my action class.

```
package actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class AjaxTest extends ActionSupport{
    public String execute(){
        return "success";
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```
<package name="basicstruts" extends="json-default">
<action name="AjaxTest" class="actions.AjaxTest">
  <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
    <result name  = "success">hello.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
```

And lastly the index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <s:url id="ajaxTest" value="/AjaxTest.action"/>

    <sj:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxTest}" target="div1">
      Update Content
    </sj:a>
  </body>
</html>
```